# Python code for searching through a url

Tags: python

Hey so im trying to get the current oil price and then do some math on it for a hw assignment. Im having trouble getting it to find the numbers i need on the website.
here is my code

```
    # Module oilcost.py to compute the delivery cost for home heating oil.
# Assume your delivery company charges a 10% fee on top of the price 
# per gallon.  The module should take one command line argument 
# indicating the number of gallons needed and should output the 
# total cost.

import sys
import re
import urllib



def getOilPrice(url):
    f = urllib.urlopen(url)
    html=f.read()
    f.close()
    match = re.search(r'<span class="dailyPrice">( d+.? d+)</span>', html)
    return match.group(1) if match else '0'

def outputPrice(oilprice, gallons, total):
    print 'The current oil price is $ %s' %oilprice


def main():
    url = 'http://www.indexmundi.com/commodities/?commodity=heating-oil'
    oilprice = float(getOilPrice(url))     # Create this method
    gallons = float(sys.argv[1])                      # Get from command line
    total = (gallons * 1.1) * oilprice
    outputPrice(oilprice, gallons, total)  # Create this method
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

can anyone let me know what im doing wrong?

Comment: my output after i get it working would be     print 'The current oil price is $ %s  \nThe total price of %s gallons is $ %s.'  % (oilprice,gallons,total)

Comment: I think what Ignacio is saying is that you aren't having a problem with the url, but rather, the *HTML resource* at that address.  specifically, you're trying to deal with HTML, which is a different beast entirely from URL's.  It's immaterial that you happen to get that HTML by downloading it at some url.  It could just as easily have been a file on disk or a literal string in your python script and you'd have the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Parsing html is notiorusly fraught with peril;](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/65696) but for the purposes of homework, that might not be so important;  This is a pretty good chance to learn about regular expressions.

on the line:

```
match = re.search(r'<span class="dailyPrice">( d+.? d+)</span>', html)
#                                              ^    ^
```

you have some `d`'s, which will match the literal letter `d`.  could you have possibly meant `\d` (that's a backslash)?

Comment: And, do you really want the space before the first digit, and the digits after the (optional) decimal point?

Answer (score 1):

Your regex doesn't match the page content. You have:

```
( d+.? d+)
```

But the page has:

```
3.23
```

Your regex matches: a space, followed by one or more `d` characters, followed by an any optional character, followed by a space, followed by one or more `d` characters. This might work better:

```
(\d+(\.\d+)?)
```

Which is: one or more digits, followed by an optional group consisting of a literal `.` character and one or more digits.

Comment: i wish i could accept both your answers, but tokenmacguy was first. Thanks for your help however!